# What exactly is scAddress in SmsManager's sendTextMessage function?

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm working on an application that will be sending a text message to another person from the app (this is not being published to the Play Store). I am looking at the documentation for SmsManager, and there is a parameter (which I currently have null), `scAddress`, which is described by:

> String: is the service center address or null to use the current default SMSC

In short, I don't want the app to use my actual phone number to send out this text message. What exactly is the "service center address?"

My application does not care about receiving a response for the text message. What happens if the user replies to this message? Is this related to the service center address?

Thank you!

Comment: A service center handles intermediate message transfer and storage. Changing that to anything other than what your carrier assigns is pretty much guaranteed to result in failure. It will not help you to hide or alter the sender's address on messages.

Comment: So in the case that the user responds to the message sent by the app, is it sent directly to my phone or is it dropped since the app does not have permission to read/receive SMS?

Comment: Your app's permissions don't affect the device's overall functionality. The device will still receive the message. It's just a regular ol' SMS message, as far as the system is concerned.

Comment: That's too bad, but it definitely makes sense. Unless there is a way to prevent responses related to the app's outgoing SMS, I will just have to deal with the spam if anyone decides to reply. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are ways to ignore incoming messages, depending on your situation. Prior to KitKat (4.4), it might be possible to intercept and abort incoming messages before other apps - including the platform SMS app - receive them. Since KitKat, if your app is set as the default SMS app, it is responsible for saving incoming messages, and can opt not to do so. I mention this, because it sounds like you might be doing a custom personal or one-off app.

Comment: My app will be distributed to a few select friends. I'm not really concerned about spam, I was just wondering if it was possible for some practice. They might jokingly respond to the text message or something, but I can just delete them. I know that I could intercept incoming messages through the app, but I don't know how I would distinguish which messages to keep and which to throw away.